# My AJAX Post responds with the HTML of a file

Tags: php, ajax

My problem is a complex one and I will analyze it at the end of my question. I have created a site and made it so that every .php file in /view should have a .php with the same name in /controller. This way I have two home.php, two login.php, etc. I have created an AJAX call so I can transfer some data to PHP.

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
$all_url = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = explode('/', $all_url[0]);

//Homepage
if (empty($url[1])) {
$url[1] = 'frontpage';
}

//DB connect
$config = array(
'host' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB SERVER
'user' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB USER
'password' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB PASSWORD
'database' => 'xxx' //CHANGE THIS, DB NAME
);
$DB = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['database'], $config['user'], $config['password']);
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$DB->exec("SET names utf8");

if (file_exists('controller/' . $url[1] . '.php')) {

$gtpl = 'main';
$restricted = array('cart');

if (!isset($_SESSION['firstVisit']) && $url[1]!='frontpage') {
    $_SESSION['firstVisit'] = false; //ensures we never enter this clause again
    require 'controller/frontpage.php';
}else if (empty($_SESSION['uid']) && in_array($url[1], $restricted)) {
    //not logged in, but trying to access restricted page.
    require 'controller/login.php';
}else{
    require 'controller/' . $url[1] . '.php';
}

require 'view/' . $gtpl . '.php';
} else {
echo 'ERROR - File not found!!!';

}
```

**main.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    media="screen"/>

    "My styles"

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <?php require 'view/frontend/'.$tpl.'.php';?>

    </div>

    "My .js scripts"

</body>
```

**main.js**

```
$('#your_button').bind("click", function() {

    var json_data = {"category": "A", "size": "20"};

    $.ajax({
        url: 'home',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: json_data,
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.error) {
                window.location.reload(true);
                alert('k');
            } else {
                alert('error!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Because of my index.php I don't need to have url: 'home.php', but this creates a problem: I can't target a specific file, for example the home.php located in /controller. Whenever I write url: 'home.php' or url: 'controller/home' I get the error at the end of my index.php - "'ERROR - File not found!!!';". When I leave the url as it is in my main.js right now, I get a response of the entire HTML code of the home.php, located in view plus the main.php. I can't seem to understand how this happens. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You can use custom parameter in ajax request and override your current functionality in `index.php`. See my answer for further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override your functionality in your `index.php` . For example, send another parameter like, `custom=true` in your ajax request;

```
....
url: 'home.php?custom=true',
....
```

And in `index.php`;

```
.....
if (!isset($_SESSION['firstVisit']) && $url[1]!='frontpage') {
    $_SESSION['firstVisit'] = false; //ensures we never enter this clause again
    require 'controller/frontpage.php';
}else if (empty($_SESSION['uid']) && in_array($url[1], $restricted)) {
    //not logged in, but trying to access restricted page.
    require 'controller/login.php';
}else{
    require 'controller/' . $url[1] . '.php';
}

$path = (empty($_GET["custom"])) ? 'view/' . $gtpl . '.php' : $gtpl;

require $path;

..........
```

Above code will require the exact url that you specified in ajax url.